# Eclim problems not being highlighted/problems not being shown in minibuffer

Tags: syntax-highlighting, java

I know I have eclim setup correctly because everything else works, I.E I can do autocomplete, jump to definition etc. I can even see problems with eclim-problems. However, when I make a syntax error, the error is not being highlighted with a red line like I thought it should do. Is there anything I have to turn on?

I even checked my faces and found eclim-problems-highlight-error-face and it has a nice red underline like it should. Everything works except for the highlighting itself.

Edit: O.K weirdly the problem seems to have half fixed itself. It must have been hung or something. However, there is now a new problem. When I mouse over the problems highlighted, it doesn't tell me what the problem is in the minibuffer like I would expect